# Can't isolate $x$ for this equation

Tags: calculus

This homework question is finding absolute max and min of a function...I've taken the derivative but I can't seem to solve for $f '(x) = 0$ on it. I've been at this for a few hours so maybe I am overlooking an obvious solution but I keep ending up with the same unsolved expression.

Original equation is

$\ f(x) = \arctan(x) - x^3$

then I try to solve the derivative at $0$ and I get it

$\ 0 =\frac{1}{1+x^2} - 3x^2 $

I apologize if this is a silly question but what I've ended up with repeatedly is $0 = 3x^4 + 3x^2 - 1$ and I'm not sure how to isolate $x$ from there. Tried some manipulations with $\ln$ but nothing came of that.

Comment: Try substituting $y$ instead of $x^2$; you will get $3y^2+3y-1 = 0$. Does this look familiar?

Comment: Don't get so caught up in the algebra that you forget to check the values at the ends of the interval, assuming you were given an interval less than infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Set $u= x^2$, and solve the *quadratic* equation $$3u^2 + 3u - 1 = 0$$
This can be done by the quadratic formula, or by completing the square. Then go back to $x$.

Comment: Just letting you know that it should be $3u^2+3u-1=0$, not $3u^2+3u+1=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I was in the process of experimenting with that but I wasn't sure if it was a viable solution. I'll continue going that route.

Comment: @ChristopherToni Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $3x^4+3x^2-1=0$ is a quadratic equation in the variable $x^2$. You may find that it helps actually to write out the substitution $u=x^2$, making the equation $3u^2+3u-1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $|arctan(x)| < \pi/2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence, as $x^3$ will "explode" for $x \to +-\infty$, the function $f(x)$ has no *absolute* maximum or minimum. It goes to $-\infty$ for $x \to +\infty$ and to $+\infty$ for $x \to -\infty$.